# Example of an additive functor admitting no right derived functor

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors, derived-categories

What would be a simple example of an additive functor $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C'$ of abelian categories such that the right derived functor
$$
RF:\text D(\mathcal C)\to\text D(\mathcal C')
$$ 
does **not** exist?

My reference for the notions involved in this post is the book **Categories and Sheaves** by Kashiwara and Schapira.

Here is a reminder of the definition of a right derived functor $RF$ in the above setting: Let $\text K(F):\text K(\mathcal C)\to\text K(\mathcal C')$ be the triangulated functor induced by $F$ between the homotopy categories, and let $Q:\text K(\mathcal C)\to\text D(\mathcal C)$ and $Q':\text K(\mathcal C')\to\text D(\mathcal C')$ be the localization functors. A left Kan extension $RF$ of $Q'\circ\text K(F)$ along $Q$ (assuming that such exists) is a right derived functor for $F$ if, for any functor $G:\text D(\mathcal C')\to\mathcal A$, the functor $G\circ RF$ is, in a natural way, a left Kan extension of $G\circ Q'\circ\text K(F)$ along $Q$.

Here is an equivalent definition: Assume that for all $X$ in $\text K(\mathcal C)$ the colimit
$$
\operatorname*{colim}_{X\to Y}\ (Q'\circ\text K(F))(Y),
$$ 
where $X\to Y$ runs over all the quasi-isomorphisms out of $X$ in $\text K(\mathcal C)$, exists in $\text D(\mathcal C')$, and denote this colimit by $RF(X)$. Then $RF$ is a right derived functor for $F$ if, for any functor $G:\text D(\mathcal C')\to\mathcal A$, the colimit
$$
\operatorname*{colim}_{X\to Y}\ (G\circ Q'\circ\text K(F))(Y)
$$ 
exists in $\mathcal A$ and coincides with $G(RF(X))$ for all $X$ in $\text K(\mathcal C)$.

Comment: Well, it is not an answer, but if the category $\mathcal{C}$ has enough injectives, the derived functor will always exist. So to find a counter-example, we must start with a category without enough injectives. For example you can take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the category of finitely generated groups.

Comment: @C.Dubussy - Thanks! Consider the following statement: "Let $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C'$ be an additive functor of abelian categories. If $\mathcal C$ has enough injectives, then $RF$ exists." Are you claiming that the above statement is true? (Note that the derived categories considered here are unbounded.)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, I thought you spoke about $D^+(\mathcal{C})$. (This is the usual context in Kashiwara/Schapira's papers.) Hence, I can't prove your statement. However, I still think that an easy conter-example should be found in a category without enough injectives, I will think about that. This is a pretty natural question without well-known answer on the internet.

Comment: Sequel: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2192221/660

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow http://mathoverflow.net/q/265098/461

Comment: This question has been answered by Yonatan Harpaz on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/a/265142/461